# PS4 Drops internet connection more often

Tags: ps4

I've just purchased a PS4 a week ago, and I'm observing after running for some minutes or an hour it usually drops the internet connection and got hang at setting up the network connection option, Is there anything wrong with the latest update?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use wifi as there can be issues sometimes. Your best bet is to plug it in wired.